# custom query/get_posts and qtranslate (url not language specific)

Tags: plugin-qtranslate

I'm using allot of custom queries, and qtranslate. Qtranslate works with everything that has home url in it. But for posts /thumb permalinks if I change language to Russian for example links remain default language specific.

So if I'm browsing /ru/ links on that page lack /ru/ so I get redirected back to default language. Does anyone know simple solution?

I've digged extensively and found this: `qtrans_convertURL( 'http://www.mysite.com/post-name/' );` I could use this and put all my permalinks within this function. But there should be a simpler solution, right?

Comment: If there's a public API function from the plugin, why not use it?

Comment: @kaiser I was thinking this would be automatic. In header I've get_permalink for navigation and it works fine url gets appended with correct/current lang. But inside loop where I've the_permalink it doesn't work. I will substitute all the_permalinks with get_ version and see if that works.

Comment: @SandroDzneladze it should work with both functions, `qtrans_convertURL()` is used as callback for `post_link` and `the_permalink` filters.

Comment: @Mamaduka on further investigation I noticed that links don't work only for custom post types. Any thoughts why?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.

For the reference problem was links in custom post types. As it appears Qtranslate in its current iteration doesn't support custom post types. And the_permalink or get_permalink will not change to current lang as you switch them.

Solution was very simple.

Just include this in functions.php file of your theme.

```
add_filter('post_type_link',     'qtrans_convertURL');
```

cheers!

Answer (score -1):

```
 //this code solves most qtranslate issues
//add (/ru) to custom menu links created in menu section
function qtrans_menuitem( $menu_item ) {
if ($menu_item->type == 'custom' && stripos($menu_item->url, get_site_url()) !== false){
    $menu_item->url = qtrans_convertURL($menu_item->url);
}
return $menu_item;
}
add_filter('wp_setup_nav_menu_item', 'qtrans_menuitem', 0);

//add (/ru) to get_permalink($custom_post)
add_filter('post_type_link', 'qtrans_convertURL');
```

Comment: Please explain why this answer is helpful. Just code isn't.